# Can b&&0 be optimized

Tags: c++, c, compiler-optimization, boolean-expression

I know that C/C++ uses the short-circuit evaluation to evaluate the expression of boolean. For example, C/C++ will definitely evaluate the operand `a` before the operand `b` in the expression `a && b`, if `a` is false, `b` won't be evaluated.

Besides, I know that things like `5==6` may be totally ignored by the compiler because it is a constant expression, which can be evaluated at compile time.

But I don't know if `b && 0` can be optimized by compiler? Can compiler say: OK, the evaluation of `0` is much easier than the evaluation of `b`, and `b` hasn't any side effect, so I decide to change `b && 0` into `0 && b` to evaluate `0` first.

Comment: Depends on the compiler - easiest if you have a look at the assembled output.  Unless b is a function, the compiler might not even generate any code because the expression is always false.

Comment: If `b` has no observable behavior and a compiler can prove it, it will very likely not evaluate it at runtime. Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/scs3je. Note that this is not about `0` being evaluated first; it's about the _as-if_ rule.

Comment: @DanielLangr So what if `b` is a function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two independent problems involved in your question. The first is that when a compiler "sees" that the `if` condition is always `false` (due to `&& 0`), it can completely throw away the corresponding branch. Example translation unit:

```
bool f(int);

int main()
{
  if (f(1) && 0)
    return 1;
}
```

With enabled optimizations, there will be very likely no machine code generated for the branch. However, the `f(1)` expression must be still evaluated at runtime, since the compiler cannot prove that the `f(1)` call has no observable behavior.

Machine code: https://godbolt.org/z/sEMrfh

On the contrary, if the compiler could prove that `f(1)` had no observable behavior, it could eliminate its call away. This has nothing to do with the order of evaluation, but with the *as-if* rule instead. Demo translation unit:

```
static bool f(int i)
{
  int j = i + 1;
  return true;
}

int main()
{
  if (f(1) && 0)
    return 1;
}
```

Machine code: https://godbolt.org/z/scs3je

Answer (score 3):

The `&&` and `||` operators guarantee left-to-right evaluation. Evaluation meaning that the compiler has to check the operand for side effects and if any are present, it must execute those. And if the left operand of `&&` evaluates to zero, it will not evaluate the right one.

Consider `if(func() && 0) { do_stuff(); }`. Even though the `&&` expression can never be true, the function must still be executed. The compiler isn't going to do some strange re-ordering such as `0 && func()`, it will rather just replace the whole expression with `func();`, removing the `if` and `do_stuff()` both.

In general, the compiler is specifically not allowed to re-order the evaluation or execution of the operands of `&&` and `||`; they have a so-called *sequence point* between evaluation of the left and the right operand. Which in turn allows code like `(ptr=malloc(...)) && (*ptr = x)` to be well-defined and not access a null pointer in case `malloc` fails.